# Pixel as decimal for aspect ratio of a div with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently using the aspect ratio of a background image to size the Div containing it.

I'm using padding-bottom (imgwidth / imgheight * w) to give it it's "responsive height".

It lines up perfectly until I start zooming in and out for different screen sizes. 100% width and above is perfect (only because I lock the max size at 1500 or I guess I'd have the same issue otherwise).

But zooming in at for example 90% I start getting gaps between the two as I have two background divs one on top of the other.

It's being caused because, for example:

```
padding-bottom: calc(100% * 600 / 1500);
```

Is returning a decimal point when zoomed in and the value is being rounded up for pixels.

Is there a solution to this? Or some javascript that can correct it?

Comment: What do you want to exactly achieve? No-repeat, full cover background, cropped if it is too wide or too long?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `background-size: cover;`